# cassandra “map” column type, mapping literals

Tags: dictionary, cassandra

My question is, that if map data type of Cassandra supports 3 literals.. in example below, a mapping between two literals is declared..

```
CREATE TABLE abc(id text PRIMARY KEY, fans map<text, text>);
```

Can I use...

```
CREATE TABLE abc(id text PRIMARY KEY, fans map<text, text, int>);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to BryceAtNetwork23's answer, you can also create a map of text -> (text, int) in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE abc (
  id text PRIMARY KEY,
  fans map<text,frozen<tuple<text,int>>>
);
```

You can then make updates like:

```
update abc set fans = {'a' : ('hello', 1) } where id = 'helloworld';
```

And retrieve data like:

```
cqlsh:test> select * from abc;

  id         | fans
 ------------+---------------------
  helloworld | {'a': ('hello', 1)}
```

Comment: I was so stuck on keeping the 3 values together, that I didn't think of a two-value tuple nested in a map.  That's probably closer to what the OP wants.  Brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

A map isn't going to work that way.  Instead, try using a LIST of [TUPLE](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/tupleType.html) like this:

```
CREATE TABLE abc(
  id text PRIMARY KEY,
  fans List<FROZEN<TUPLE<text, text, int>>>
);
```

Note that you'll also need to use the [FROZEN](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html#reference_ds_v3f_vfk_xj__tuple-udt-columns) keyword, which is required for tuples and user defined types.